# lookup tables with multiple (possibly partly empty key columns) - prefer specific match over general one

Tags: r, sql, data-table

Assume I have a table with samples:

| ID | sample type | origin | project_l1 | project_l2 | project_l3 | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | DNA | Blood | p1 | p1.1 | p1.1.1 | p1... |
| 2 | DNA | Blood | p1 | p1.1 | p1.1.2 | p1... |
| 3 | DNA | Blood | p1 | p1.1 |  |  |
| 4 | DNA | Blood | p1 | p1.2 | p1.2.1 | p1... |
| 5 | DNA | Blood | p1 |  |  |  |
| 6 | DNA | Blood | p2 |  |  |  |

Assume further I have a lookup table for some certain characteristics, in particular some template names

| sample type | origin | project_l1 | project_l2 | ... | SOP_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| DNA | Blood |  |  |  | B2D |
| DNA | Blood | p1 |  |  | B2Dp1 |
| DNA | Blood | p1 | p1.1 |  | B2Dp1.1 |
| DNA | Blood | p1 | p1.1 | p1.1.1 | B2Dp1.1.1 |

Now I'd like to lookup the SOP name in the 2nd table using following logic:

1. Build ranking from most specific match to less specific matches
2. Use lookup with highest rank available
3. For every sample we already have made sure that there is at least one SOP that can be applied

like:

1. for all DNA samples obtained from blood in project p1.1.1 use SOP B2Dp1.1.1 if there is an entry for this level, otherwise use a more general one (the most specific that is available)
2. for all DNA samples obtained from blood in project p1.1 which are not in p1.1.1 use SOP B2Dp1.1
3. for all DNA samples obtained from blood in project p1 which are not in p1.1 use SOP B2Dp1
4. for all DNA samples obtained from blood in a project different from p1 use the generic SOP B2D as long as there is no other more specific match
5. do the same for the other projects (like p2, p2.1, p2.2, p2.1.1,p2.1.2 etc)

Additional challenge: I have to avoid creating duplicate lookup entries.

Presently I'm trying to obtain the matches using either R (data.table) or sql (via sqldf within R). I'd also like to avoid hard coding each level of the project hierarchy.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think creating keys on both tables by going from the lowest level to the highest will work. In SQL:

```
select table1.*, coalesce(table2.SOP_name, 'B2D') as SOP_name
from table1
left join table2 on coalesce(table1.project_l3, table1.project_l2, table1.project_l1) = coalesce(table2.project_l3, table2.project_l2, table2.project_l1)
```